# parse value from a dictionary/list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, nsxmlparser, libxml2

I have a dictionary/list balance_sign_dict from which I need to retrieve 2 values based on condition. 
The source XML for this is;

```
<Value>
<Signature>-873</Signature>
<Amount>1501042000</Amount>
</Value>
```

I want to parse data from the dict shown below;
Could you please tell me how do I parse conditional data (e.g. if I want the value of "Amount" node for "Signature" node having -873) i.e. it should return me 1501042000

I want a generic way of parsing the values from the dictionary below.

Printing description of balance_sign_dict:

```
(
        {
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "-873";
                nodeName = Signature;
            },
                        {
                nodeContent = 1501042000;
                nodeName = Amount;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Value;
    },
        {
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "-1228";
                nodeName = Signature;
            },
                        {
                nodeContent = 428586000;
                nodeName = Amount;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Value;
    },
        {
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "-1140";
                nodeName = Signature;
            },
                        {
                nodeContent = 79370000;
                nodeName = Amount;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Value;
    },
```

Here is what I am trying now;

```
for (NSDictionary *valueNode in balance_sign_dict){
            for (NSArray *nodeChildArray in [valueNode objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"]){
                NSString *tmpNodeName = [nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:1];
                NSDictionary *tmpD = [valueNode objectAtIndex:1];


                if ([tmpNodeName isEqualToString:@"Signature"]) {
                    tmpSignVal = [nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    if ([tmpSignVal isEqualToString:@"-873"]) {
                        tmpSignAmt = [nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:1];
                    }
                }
```

But for some reason the 2nd part of nodeChildArray gets removed...i.e. nodeContent = 1501042000;
                nodeName = Amount;

I am not sure how to access that part.

Please help.
                }
            }

Actually here is what i get during alternate runs;

Printing description of nodeChildArray:
{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    0 : {contents = "nodeName"} = {contents = "Signature"}
    1 : {contents = "nodeContent"} = {contents = "-1507"}
}

Printing description of nodeChildArray:
{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    0 : {contents = "nodeName"} = {contents = "Amount"}
    1 : {contents = "nodeContent"} = {contents = "631000"}
}

How do I get the Amount value for matching Signature value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are the best container classes that I know of in any language that I am experienced with.  `NSDictionary` can store any object or primitive, including an `NSArray`, and vice versa.  When I say dictionary I am arbitrarily referring to either class.

When you output the description of any dictionary (which is as simple as `NSLog(@"%@",myDict);`, the entire contents of the dictionary are displayed like an XML (or maybe more accurately a JSON) document.  It is easy to look at the content of the dictionary description to determine what is contained inside.  `()` denotes an `NSArray` and `{}` denotes an `NSDictionary`.

```
// this is the beginning of an array.
(
        // this is the beginning of index 0 of the array, an `NSDictionary`
        {
        // objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
        nodeChildArray =         ( // inside nodeChildArray is another array
                        { // index 0 of array is a dictionary with two keys
                // objectForKey:@"nodeContent" == @"-873"
                nodeContent = "-873";
                // objectForKey:@"nodeName" == @"Signature"
                nodeName = Signature;
            }, // end of index 0
                        { // index 1 of array
                nodeContent = 1501042000;
                nodeName = Amount;
            } // end of index 1
        ); // end of nodeChildArray, an NSArray stored at objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"
        // this is the only other element in the dictionary, a string
        // objectForKey:@"nodeName"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
        nodeName = Value;
    }, // end of the dictionary containing nodeChildArray and nodeName
        { // objectAtIndex:1
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "-1228";
                nodeName = Signature;
            },
                        {
                nodeContent = 428586000;
                nodeName = Amount;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Value;
    },
        { // objectAtIndex:2
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "-1140";
                nodeName = Signature;
            },
                        {
                nodeContent = 79370000;
                nodeName = Amount;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Value;
    },
);
```

So you can see from looking at your `NSDictionary` debug output that it's actually an `NSArray`.  The order of structures is `NSArray->NSDictionary->NSArray->NSString <--> [[[[NSArray objectAtIndex:i] NSDictionary objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"] NSArray objectAtIndex:j] NSDictionary objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]`, finally returning an `NSString`.  Use this as the most recent code - in the last version of the code I passed `balance_sign_dict` as an `NSDictionary`.  *This might have even worked!*  But it is much better form to cast the argument properly.  If you don't know whether or not your dictionary is going to start with an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary`, you can cast it as an `id` and check its type with `[theIdObject isKindOfClass:[{NSArray,NSDictionary} class]]`.  Don't use the `{}` and choose one of the two in your code.

```
-(NSDictionary*)parseBalance:(NSArray*)balance_sign_dict
{
  NSMutableDictionary* theResults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  for( NSDictionary* nodeDict in balance_sign_dict )
  {
    NSArray* nodeChildArray = [nodeDict objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];
    [theResults addObject:[[nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"] forKey:[[nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]];
  }
  return theResults;
}
```

Comment: Hey Thomson...Thanks a lot..the answer seems to be along the lines of what i am looking for...But just one questions;
can i use the function to return the value based on what is passed for Signature 
e.g. if I want the value of "Amount" node for "Signature" node having -873) i.e. it should return me 1501042000
i.e. if I pass signature "-873" to the function, it should return me 1501042000

Comment: @Thomson Comer : There seems to be some issue with the type of nodeChildArray. It actually seems to be returning a dict and not an array. I just checked in the debugger and as a result I am still not getting the correct result.

Comment: hmthur, sorry, I see where my mistake was.  I updated the answer and it should now do what you are asking.  You'll get back an NSDictionary where saying [myDict objectForKey:@"-873"] will return 1501042000 for all the elements in balance_sign_dict.

Comment: @Thomson Comer: No need to say sorry. Instead I should say thank you for all the help you have provided. Just to confirm, I'll add the function parseBalance: which you have updated and call it using;
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *tmpStr;
 
myDict = [self parseBalance:balance_sign_dict];
tmpStr = [myDict objectForKey:@"-873"];

Do I need to pass self.balance_sign_dict or just balance_sign_dict?

Could you please confirm if my approach is now correct?

Comment: As you wrote, myDict will actually become a memory leak since you allocate it and then immediately overwrite it with the return result of parseBalance:.  Instead, just say `NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [self parseBalance:balance_sign_dict];`.  If you need to store myDict in a member variable that exists when you exit the current scope, you'll have to retain it.  I don't think you need to pass self.balance_sign_dict.  As long as the `@property` isn't set to `readonly` I don't think that there's any difference between self.balance_sign_dict and balance_sign_dict when you are reading the value.

Comment: ok..thanks a lot for the info...I'll be able implement the solution given by you after abt 12 hrs from now (coz of some ext api lmitation) and get back to u.

But again..thanks a ton for all the help you have provided.

Comment: While I need to wait for some time to test the code, just needed a quick confirmation going through your code. Basically the line
NSArray* nodeChildArray = [nodeDict objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];

I hope it actually returns an array and not a dict, as was happening previously. I am not sure why that was happening.
Again I need to wait and test it out.

Comment: hmthur I added lots of discussion on how I made `parseBalance:` and a minor change to the message.

Comment: YOU TRULY ROCK ***THOMSON*** I COULD NOT GET ANY BETTER DESCRIPTION THAN WHAT YOU HAVE GIVEN...NOT EVEN FROM APPLE'S DOCUMENTTION !! A 7-STAR TO YOU !!!!